# google pub sub delay message per ordering key

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have successfully subscribe the message from `Google Pub/Sub`.
In my Pub/Sub topic, I have the ordering key.
what I want to achieve is that, I should only read 1 message per ordering key, and then add a delay for subscribing it.

here is what I have written

```
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageReceiver
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber

val receiver = MessageReceiver { message, consumer ->
        GlobalScope.launch {
            delay(10 * 1000L)
            println(message.data.toStringUtf8())
            consumer.ack()
        }
    }
subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver).build()
subscriber!!.startAsync().awaitRunning()
```

When I publish 5 message with the same ordering key at once to the PubSub, here is the result.

after 60 seconds, it will print the 1st message
after the next 60 seconds, it prints the next 4 message at once

how should I change it so that in the next 60 seconds, it also only read 1 message per ordering key?

P.S. Seems like changing `GlobalScope.launch` and `delay` to `Thread.sleep` can solve the issue. but Can't I use a non-blocking delay/sleep?

Comment: Using sleep in an async function is not good programming. The receiver will be called for each message. Sleeping is the wrong approach. The behavior you see might be caused by how many threads can run at the same time. Your question does not have details on the runtime environment.

Comment: Also do not delay the message ACK by sleeping.

Comment: hi @JohnHanley Im using `kotlin` with the framework of `Quarkus`. But I just try it on my local env. Then what is the better approach to delay the message that I receive? the delay should be per ordering key

Comment: Seems like this has nothing to do with the `Google Cloud Platform`, instead it has something to do with the `GlobalScope.launch`. Changing it to a `runBlocking` with `delay` also solve the issue for it to have a non-blocking delay